# Rails Many To Many, add records with extra information

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many, has-many-through

I have a many to many relationships that uses a through model:

game.rb:

```
has_many :shows, dependent: :destroy
has_many :users, :through => :shows
```

user.rb

```
has_many :shows
has_many :games, :through => :shows
```

show.rb

```
belongs_to :game
belongs_to :user
```

Now I'm adding games to a user this way:

```
game.users << special_users
game.users << non_special_users
```

While adding users to a game, I would like to specify what type of users in a way that when looking at a show element, I know it's coming from a special user. How can I do that?
Note that special users is dynamic so it's not found anywhere else, it's only found in the relationship between a game and a user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways you can do this.  The simplest way would be to add the shows directly:

```
game.shows << special_users.map{|u| Show.new(user: u, special: true) }
game.shows << non_special_users.map{|u| Show.new(user: u, special: false) }
```

Alternatively, you can create associations that have the 'special' condition baked-in:

```
#game.rb
has_many :special_shows, lambda{ where(special: true) }, class_name: 'Show'
has_many :non_special_shows, lambda{ where(special: false) }, class_name: 'Show'
has_many :special_users, through: :special_shows, source: user
has_many :non_special_users, through: :non_special_shows, source: user

game.special_users << special_users
game.non_special_users << non_special_users
```

If you don't want to set up a new scope for special and non-special `shows`, you can make the distinction on the `users` association:

```
has_many :shows
has_many :special_users, lambda{ where(shows: {special: true}) }, through: :shows, source: :user
has_many :non_special_users, lambda{ where(shows: {special: false}) }, through: :shows, source: :user
```

Note that in earlier versions of Rails, the `lambda` scope condition is not supported.  In this case, add a `conditions:` value to the options hash:

```
has_many :special_shows, class_name: 'Show', conditions: {special: true}
has_many :non_special_shows, class_name: 'Show', conditions: {special: false}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, a very elegant solution.